# Playing sound files on a remote machine through the local computer's speakers

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mp3, osx-mountain-lion, remote-server

I have a Ubuntu server at home where I have a lot of music files backed up. The machine doesn't have a sound card/speakers connected to it.

My local computer is a MacBook Pro and what I would like to do is to be able to ssh into that remote machine where the mp3 files are (which I've already got set up) and be able to play them on my laptop's (aka local computer's) speakers. I've tried out mpg123 on my MacBook, which works great and would appear to be what I'm looking for to play the audio files in the command line, but if I am ssh'd into my remote machine how would I pipe the audio output through to my local machine so that the sound comes out of its speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, with the help of my roommate! :D

I used [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount the remote file system and [cmus](http://cmus.sourceforge.net/) to play the music. I'm currently sitting in the kitchen and listening to music that is on a machine in our rec room upstairs :)